# How to get the exact authorization status of location service?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager

If user has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or location services are disabled in Settings, it will return Denied status. How can I know the exact reason of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I've made this two function to check for each case**

---

**If user explicitly denied authorization for your app only you can check it like this,**

```
+ (BOOL) isLocationDisableForMyAppOnly
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] &&
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

**If location services are disabled in Settings,**

```
+ (BOOL) userLocationAvailable {
    return [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
}
```

**And I'm using it like this,**

```
if([UserLocation userLocationAvailable]) {
    //.... Get location.
}
else
{
    if([UserLocation isLocationDisableForMyAppOnly]) {
        //... Location not available. Denied accessing location.
    }
    else{
        //... Location not available. Enable location services from settings.
    }
}
```

<sub>P.S. UserLocation is a custom class to get user location.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

**Swift**

Use:

```
CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
```

To get the authorization status. It's a `CLAuthorizationStatus`, you can switch on the different status' like this:

```
let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
switch status {
    case .authorizedAlways:
        <#code#>
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        <#code#>
    case .denied:
        <#code#>
    case .notDetermined:
        <#code#>
    case .restricted:
        <#code#>
}
```

Comment: how can I tell what the user selected? AKA how can I know _when_ the user has selected something from the "allow...to access your location" modal?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift:**

**I've made this two function to check for each case**

**If user explicitly denied authorization for your app only you can check it like this,**

```
class func isLocationDisableForMyAppOnly() -> Bool {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**If location services are disabled in Settings,**

```
class func userLocationAvailable() -> Bool {
    return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
}
```

**And I'm using it like this,**

```
if UserLocation.userLocationAvailable() {
        //.... Get location.
} else {
    if UserLocation.isLocationDisableForMyAppOnly() {
        //... Location not available. Denied accessing location.
    } else {
        //... Location not available. Enable location services from settings.
    }
}
```

<sub>P.S. `UserLocation` is a custom class to get user location.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.0 iOS 14.0

Since `'authorizationStatus()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0` you should use the instance directly.

`authorizationStatus` is now a property of `CLLocationManager`.

You can use the following example:

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager {
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus {
        locationManager.authorizationStatus
    }
}
```

Have also a look at this question: [AuthorizationStatus for CLLocationManager is deprecated on iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073811/authorizationstatus-for-cllocationmanager-is-deprecated-on-ios-14)