# AuthorizationStatus for CLLocationManager is deprecated on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios14

I use this code to check if I have access to the user location or not

```swift
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .restricted, .denied:
            hasPermission = false
        default:
            hasPermission = true
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }
}
```

And Xcode(12) yells at me with this warning:

```
'authorizationStatus()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0
```

So what is the replacement?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It is now a property of `CLLocationManager`, [`authorizationStatus`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3563952-authorizationstatus). So, create a `CLLocationManager` instance:

```swift
let manager = CLLocationManager()
```

Then you can access the property from there:

```swift
switch manager.authorizationStatus {
case .restricted, .denied:
    ...
default:
    ...
}
```

There are a few location related changes in iOS 14. See WWDC 2020 [What's new in location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10660/#).

---

Needless to say, if you also need to support iOS versions prior to 14, then just add the `#available` check, e.g.:

```swift
let authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus

if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    authorizationStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
} else {
    authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
}

switch authorizationStatus {
case .restricted, .denied:
    ...
default:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this Static member 'manager' cannot be used on instance of type 'CLLocationManager'

Comment: Bug in Xcode beta most likely if I set target to iOS 13 then both examples works using CLLocation literate as original poster and using let manager =  CLLocationManager() as you demonstrated, there is no static member error then. Weird

Comment: If you need to simultaneously support iOS 14 and earlier versions, use `#available` check.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the brackets before the dot:

```
CLLocationManager().authorizationStatus
```

Comment: Unexpected interface name 'CLLocationManager': expected expression

Answer (score 0):

Objective C Version:

In Class Interface

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

In Class Code

```
- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
}
return self;
}

-(CLLocation*)getLocation
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [self.locationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        [self promptToEnableLocationServices];
        return nil;
    }
 etc...
```